# Fetch call in componentDidMount not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jwt, components

I am working on a React app with JWT authentication. In order to set the user object in state, I first need to grab the user._id from the token in their local storage, and then run a fetch call for the entire user object fresh from the backend/MongoDB.

I am trying to do this all in a componentDidMount inside my App.jsx, however my backend controller function console.logs the req.params.id (where I attached the user._id) as null, and fails to grab the user object from the DB, returning 'null' to the frontend.

**App.jsx:**

```js
export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
      user: false,
  }

  setUserInState = (incomingUserData) => {
      this.setState({user: incomingUserData})
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
      let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      if (token) {
          const payload = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))
          if (payload.exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
              localStorage.removeItem('token')
              token = null
          } else {
            try {
              console.log('payload.user: ' + JSON.stringify(payload.user))
              let userId = payload.user._id
              await fetch(`/api/users/getProfile/${userId}`)
                  .then(res => res.json())
                  .then(data => console.log('DATA: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
                  .then(data => this.setState({user: data}))
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
            }
          }
      }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar user={this.state.user} setUserInState={this.setUserInState}/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/ideas/create' element={<NewIdea user={this.state.user} setUserInState={this.setUserInState}/>}/>
          <Route path='/users/getProfile/:userId' element={<UserProfile user={this.state.user} setUserInState={this.setUserInState}/>}/>
          <Route path='/users/editProfile' element={<EditProfile user={this.state.user} setUserInState={this.setUserInState}/>}/>
          <Route path='/publishers/becomePublisher' element={<BecomePublisher user={this.state.user} setUserInState={this.setUserInState}/>} />
          <Route path='/users/addSubscription'/>
          <Route path='/users/removeSubscription'/>
          <Route path='/publishers/show/:id' element={<PubProfile user={this.state.user}/>}/>
          <Route path='/ideas/show/:id' element={<PubIdeas user={this.state.user}/>}/>
          <Route path='/ideas/ideasFeed/:userId' element={<IdeasFeed user={this.state.user}/>}/>
          <Route path='/discover/:id' element={<Discover user={this.state.user} setUserInState={this.setUserInState}/>}/>
          <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/discover/:id' replace />}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

payload.user (userId) console.logs correctly with the user's Id.

While that compDidMount fails to set the user in state, interestingly the useEffect hook in my Discover.jsx component **does** manage to set the user in state, by doing basically the same thing.

**Discover.jsx:** (cutting off imports/return statement to save space)

```js
export default function Discover (props) {

    const [isActive, setActive] = useState({})
    const [publishers, setPublishers] = useState([])

    let handleSeeMore = (id) => {
        let temp = {...isActive}
        temp[id] = !temp[id]
        setActive(temp)
    }

    let getPublishers = async () => {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        // if there is a token/the user is signed in then fetch the user object and publishers objects both
        if (token) {
            let payload = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))
            let userId = payload.user._id
            let response = await fetch(`/api/publishers/discover/${userId}`)
                let data = await response.json()
                props.setUserInState(data.user)
                setPublishers(data.publishers)
        //otherwise just grab the publishers objects
        } else {
            let userId = 'false'
            await fetch(`/api/publishers/discover/${userId}`)
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then(data => setPublishers(data))
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        (async() => {
            await getPublishers()
        })()
    },[])
```

Comment: add a console log and to find if `userId` gets correct value (before fetch call). If it has correct value then the issue would be with backend code.

Comment: Okay it console.logs correctly. Going through backend code now

Comment: Welp that was the issue. I was using req.params.id in controller function when should have been using req.params.userId. Thanks